# Need recommendation on Live streaming IP Cameras

Tags: video-streaming, red5

I have a network of IP Cameras (all with Private IPs) connected to a central Server. The server has internet access and a public IP.

I now want to publish the streams from the IP Cameras over the internet. I would prefer to use paid services of websites like ustream, click2stream etc. But the problem is that the Cameras have Private IP address.

I also have hands on experience with Red5. Is there any way by which I can capture the streams using Red5 and publish it on any of the above website?

The solution should be capable of managing 800 cameras and 15000 viewers and also requires support for IOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it might makes more sense if you look at FFMPEG.
FFMPEG can natively stream rtmp too. And with FFMPEG I think you have more options to transcode the stream into some format that is useful.

Sebastian